# Modify an objects value in Views without modifying the data base value with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a small issue with modifying an object before it is returned in Views.py. My situation is that I have to hide/modify certain values from model objects for unsubscribed users. My current code is something like this (pseudo code):

```
ShowList(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
    """
    This view should return a list of all the Shows
    for the currently authenticated user.
    """
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    shows = Shows.objects.get(id=pk) 
    return shows
```

What I would like to do is change one object from the ones it got from the query. For example, I want to return 0/null for the object named 'video'. What I have done is:

```
shows.video = 0
shows.save()
return shows
```

The problem is that it actually overwrites the object's value in the database level. All I want is to change it temporarily before it is returned. I have also tried

`permission_classes =(subscription_permission,)`

but it blocks all the views.py. I want the unsubscribed user to see a preview of what is to be seen for a subscribed user, but not see the video. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already have a [serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) for your `Shows` objects, which serializes every attribute.

My suggestion is to create another serializer, say `UnsubscribedUserShowSerializer`, which always has `None` in the `video` attribute.

```
class ShowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Shows


class UnsubscribedUserShowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Shows

    def get_video(self, obj):
        return None
```

Then, you will override your `ShowList` view's `get_serializer_class`:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.user:
        # User is authenticated
        return ShowSerializer
    else:
        return UnsubscribedUserShowSerializer
```

By doing this, you don't need to override `get_queryset` and can easily customize what values you want to hide from unsubscribed users.

Answer (score 0):

By calling .save() method you are overwriting the value of field. You can apply check for unsubscribed user this way
    video = shows.video
    If not user_subscribed:
        video = 0